# How can I determine which column was clicked in a table using tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am using jQuery and tablesorter to add column sorting to my data on a page.

I want to to record which column was sorted. How can I determine which column was clicked? Is there an event that I can hook into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the **sortEnd** event and checking for the presence of the **.sorted-a-z** and **.sorted-z-a** classes to determine the sorted column.

```
table.bind("sortEnd", function () {
    var checkSort = function (query, order) {
        var column = table.find(query);

        if (column.length == 1){
           // Do stuff
        }
    };

    checkSort("th.sorted-a-z", "descending");
    checkSort("th.sorted-z-a", "ascending");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting your own click event on the `.tablesorter .header` should provide an easy way to getting the column clicked whilst avoiding conflicts with other tables

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign a delegate to the table and catch `click` events on `th` elements:

```
$('#table').delegate('th', 'click', function(e) {
  //e.target will point to the header that was clicked
});
```